# Array.contains in Firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How to use the JS native array.contains in Firestore rules?

```js
function isCool() {
  return [
    'xxx',
    'yyy',
  ].contains(req.auth.uid)
}
```

The function above gives an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#:%7E:text=Check%20if%20value%20v%20exists%20in%20list%20x):

```js
function isCool() {
  return request.auth.uid in ['xxx', 'yyy'];
}
```

It returns true if the value is present in the given list/array.